# JQuery dropdown additional info help

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that list users. Each table row has the users Name and Location. I want to be able to click the table row and have additional information about the user appears below the table row clicked for the user, without having to refresh the page. I am using the code below but the animation is buggy and i know there has to be a better way of doing this.

```
       <script type="text/javascript" id="js">$(document).ready(function() {
 // Drop down data on tr click
 $('#users tr').click(function () {
 //Get user ID, must be in first td
    var userID = $(this).find("td:first").html();     
 //Remove any rows being displayed from previous clicks if any
 $('#data-row').remove();
 //Insert a tr and td spanning all rows as a placeholder (display = none, we will animate next)
   $(this).after('<tr id="data-row" style="display:none;"><td id="data-cell" colspan="5"></td></tr>');
 //Show tr created above
 $('#data-row').show('400');
 //Ajax loading image while we wait for load to return
 $('#data-cell').html('<p><img src="_images/ajax-loader-2.gif" width="220" height="19" /></p>');
 //Load in data to tr td
   $('#data-cell').load('admin/main/user_info_box.php?userID='+userID);
 });
 //Removes Data if Header is clicked to sort rows
 $('th').click(function () {
  $('#data-row').remove();          
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load all of the users info at the start and .hide() it all, then do .slideToggle() on a click rather than separate AJAX calls